# choosing large subset without arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

I have stumbled upon this problem in a Number Theory book and got stuck with it.

The problem states:

Given the set $(1,2,...,N)$, Prove that if $N$ is large enough one can choose a subset of at least $N^{0.63}$ integers such that no $3$ elements chosen form an arithmetic progression.

The problem reminds me a lot of Szemerédi's Theorem, but not quite the same. Also you are not supposed to use that here, since the book has that in a later chapter.

The difficult part is that I have no clue where $0.63$ is coming from and it just makes searching for a solution or strategy way harder.

Anyone has a clue on this?

Alright. Here is what I got till now. So if we consider the numbers in base $3$ that only use $0,1$-s we get a good set. By this I mean that these numbers will not have an arithmetic progression, this can be checked easily. Now to have a bound on how many numbers are there like this we can consider that if $n$ has $3^{k-1}$ as it's highest digit in base $3$, then we can say $n^{0.63}<n^{log_3(2)}<(3^k)^{log_3(2)}=2^k$, and we can create $2^k$ numbers that have $3^{k-1}$ as their highest digit in base $3$. However this argument only holds true if $n$ is a certain type, namely all of these numbers that we can create are smaller than $n$, so $n$ is greater than $1111...1$ $(k)$ $1$-s in base $3$. But this is not exactly what the problem asks. I get that this gives infinitely many good $n$-s, like $n=4$ is a good choice, but we need something like a limit from where all numbers are good don't we?

Also I still have no idea what to make of the fact that $0.63<1-\dfrac{1}{e}$

Comment: Hint: $0.63 < 1-\frac1e$.

Comment: I think it is $\log_3(2)\approx .63$ that matters here.  Hint:  for fixed $n$ consider the set of  natural numbers $≤n$ which, in base $3$, are written without using the digit $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I can see how to finish from lulu's comment, but I don't know what to make of $1-\dfrac{1}{e}$ from @Don Thousand's comment. Can you please tell some more detail on that?

Comment: @lulu I have edited the post according to your idea. Can you fix the issue I have found, or is this the argument you found either?

Comment: All you need to do is estimate $a_n$, the number of "good" integers $≤n$.  If $f(n)=\lfloor \log_3n\rfloor +1$ it's easy to see that $a_n>2^{f(k)-1}$.  That's already enough for an asymptotic result (which is the sort of thing one usually wants here).  Maybe it's enough for a strict inequality (I'm  not sure).  Otherwise, I'd argue that $a_n=2^{f(n)}$ if $3^{f(n)}-1≤n$ and (I think) $a_n=a_{n-3^{f(n)-1}}$ otherwise (modulo minor corrections, this should be an easy induction).  That ought to be enough.

Comment: I think this is a reasonably standard argument (and better estimates can be made if you switch the base around).  [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/3apsurvey.pdf) is one reference, I'm sure you can find others.

Comment: Oh, should say, I think the $1-\frac 1e$ estimate is a numerical accident.  At least I don't see anyway to base an argument around it (which, obviously, doesn't mean that there isn't such an argument).